# Sync sharepoint documents to onedrive without clicking the "sync" button on sharepoint itself

Tags: batch-file, sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I have office 365 and would like to sync my sharepoint documents to a user's onedrive without them needing to actually go to the site first and click the "sync" button. I have a script below that almost works, but I get the error "Sorry, One drive can't add your folder right now." I've also tried to open all my settings on sharepoint in case it was a permissions issue, but nothing fixed it. Here is my batch script (which can install onedrive as well) but I took out my site info. The sync info came from using internet explorer, going to the sharepoint site, clicking the sync button, and pulling the address from the permissions pop up.

```
@Echo Off
Echo Installing OneDrive... 
START /WAIT C:\DC\OneDriveSetup.exe
Echo Enter your username below - Example - Jane.Doe@domain.com
set /p User_Name="Enter Username then press Enter - "
start "" "odopen://sync/?siteId=SiteID_HERE&webId=WebID_HERE&listId=ListID_HERE&userEmail=UserEmail_HERE&webUrl=WebURL_HERE"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sync this way:

odopen://sync?siteId=&webId=&webTitle=&listId=&listTitle=&userEmail=&listTemplateTypeId=&webUrl=&webLogoUrl=&webTemplate=&isSiteAdmin=&scope=OPENLIST

You can find the ids searching the source code the page you are trying to sync.