# How can I automatically sync shared SharePoint Documents with each user on local device without clicking on "sync" button on the SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, onedrive, office365api

I have more than 300 SharePoint sites and some sites has subsites. Each user has access to a set of sites and subsites, while some other users have access to all of these sites and subsites. I want a script to automatically sync sites and subsites documents. I saw some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50823121/sync-sharepoint-documents-to-onedrive-without-clicking-the-sync-button-on-shar), but this maps the site without checking if the user have access to it or not. Also, I have to collect the information about each site manually.

I'm using Office 365 subscription for all users.

Ultimately, I want a script that checks the sites each user has permissions to and sync these with the user's local OneDrive library.

Thanks